# GitHub: Pulling a branch in another branch

Tags: git

I have a branch (mainbranch) which is recently derived from the master.

If a do a `git pull origin otherbranch` will that merge the branch otherbranch to the mainbranch derived from master?

Git merge can be used but curious to know what will the above statement do.

What i need is to merge otherbranch with main branch and megre is giving error

```
fatal: 'otherbranch' does not point to a commit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command is equivalent to

```
git fetch origin otherbranch
git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

And will therefore:

1. Fetch the history of the remote branch `otherbranch` from remote `origin` (its head commit is temporarily saved in `FETCH_HEAD`).
2. Merge the history of `origin/otherbranch` (which is now in `FETCH_HEAD`) into the *currently checked out* branch.

Comment: so it means in my example, the otherbranch is merged to mainbranch ?

Comment: If `mainbranch` is checked out, yes.

Comment: the branch was not a local, it was branch at github, still ?

Comment: Git is always local, `fetch`/`merge` (or `pull`) fetch the history from the remote and do the merge locally. But yes, it was the branch from GitHub (or whatever `origin` points to).